# How to extract desired pattern out of line (string)

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to compare my pattern with given string (*in general I will readline out of file, but for now I use explicit string just to see how it works*) though for given line script does not work as I desire.

```
import re

regex = '.+0+[0-9]+.'
string = "Your order number is 0000122995"

print (re.match(regex,string))
```

What I am trying to achieve here is to find this `0000*` number and assign it to the variable (*which I would like to place into Excel later*), but given regex matches the whole line, which is not what I am trying to get (*I know that is because of the syntax*). Any tips how to overcome this?

Comment: Try using `(0{4})[0-9]+`

Comment: I tried it before. Returns 'None' object. I belive it may also be connected to 'match' functions while it may return object if it fully matches instead of only small pattern.

Comment: @PawełMotyka `re.match` anchors the search to the start of the string... you want `re.search`... eg: `re.search(r'(0{4}\d+)', "Your order number is 0000122995")`

Comment: `re.search(r'(0{4}\d+)', "Your order number is 0000122995").group(0)` to be exact.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to locate a match anywhere in a *string*, use `re.search()` instead of `re.match()`. `re.match()` checks for a match only at the beginning of the string, while `re.search()` checks for a match anywhere in the string.

```
import re
regex = r'(0{4}\d+)'
string = "Your order number is 0000122995"

print (re.search(regex, string).group(0))
```

`re.search()` and `re.match()` return a match object if there is a match. 
Using `match.group()` returns one or more subgroups of the match.

See the [`re.search()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/re.html#re.search) documentation for more information.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, if you expect your queries to be as consistent as you've shown the following will work(It ignores "Your order number is " and captures everything behind it until it hits whitespace or the end of the string):

```
def findOrder():
        import re
        string = "Your order number is 0000122995"
        arrayAnswer = re.findall('Your order number is ([\S]+)', string)
        print('Your number in an Array is:')
        print(arrayAnswer)
        print('')
        print('Your number(s) output as a "string(s)" is/are:')
        for order in arrayAnswer:
                print(order)
```

.

Run this by making sure to call findOrder(). If you wan to get a little more "regexy", noting that what you want exclusively includes numbers, the below excludes letters and spaces and returns numbers:

```
def findOrder():
        import re
        string = "Your order number is 0000122995"
        arrayAnswer = re.findall('[a-zA-Z\s]+([\d]+)', string)
        print('Your number in an Array is:')
        print(arrayAnswer)
        print('')
        print('Your number(s) output as a "string(s)" is/are:')
        for order in arrayAnswer:
                print(order)
```

Again, run this by making sure to call findOrder().

Your OUTPUT for both should be this:

```
>>> findOrder()
Your number in an Array is:
['0000122995']

Your number(s) output as a "string(s)" is/are:
0000122995
```

I suspect, though, you might want to work with a query longer than the string you posted. Post that if you need anything further.